# What causes error 701: Wrong authentication credentials in the Amadeus self-service API?

Tags: amadeus

I'm getting bearer tokens from https://api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token successfully, but when I pass them to any other endpoint, I'm seeing error 701: Wrong authentication credentials.

Since the authentication endpoint is returning a 2xx code and a token, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

701 Errors need to be resolved by Amadeus directly, and if it's for a new account, sometimes you just need to wait for the database to be updated with your credentials.

Comment: How long do you have to wait? It's been a couple of hours for me and I'm still hitting this problem.